# Ansible variable dictionary key not substituted

Tags: variables, ansible

I know that similar questions have been asked before, but I still can't get the results that I want in my scenario. I have the following code snippet within my `group_vars` folder. There are two BGP neighbors `(1.1.1.1 and 1.1.1.2)`, which are listed at the group level. However, I want to be able to list one ore more additional neighbors, which I want to override at the host_vars level. The substitution for variable `{{ bgp_neighbor_01 }}` does not work because as I understand, Ansible does not perform variable substitution for the dictionary keys. Is there a way to keep my first two IP addresses at the group level, but also define additional IP addresses at the host level? Thank you in advance.

```
  bgp_neighbors:
    1.1.1.1:
      peer_group: EVPN-OVERLAY-PEERS
      description: SPINE1_EVPN_ADDRESS_FAMILY
    1.1.1.2:
      peer_group: EVPN-OVERLAY-PEERS
      description: SPINE2_EVPN_ADDRESS_FAMILY
    '{{ bgp_neighbor_01 }}':              <-- this variable does not get substituted 
      peer_group: '{{ peer_group_name }}'
      description: '{{ description }}'
```

This is how I resolved my issue based on suggestion provided by Vladimir. I created the following dictionary variable in my `group_vars` file.

```
evpn_bgp_neighbors: 
  1.1.1.1:
      peer_group: EVPN-OVERLAY-PEERS
      description: SPINE1_EVPN_ADDRESS_FAMILY
  1.1.1.2:
      peer_group: EVPN-OVERLAY-PEERS
      description: SPINE2_EVPN_ADDRESS_FAMILY
```

Then, in each of my individual host files, I created host specific bgp neighbors dictionary, and then I used combine filter to combine group level and host level dictionaries.

```
underlay_bgp_neighbors:
  192.168.1.0:
    peer_group: IPv4-UNDERLAY-PEERS
    description: SPINE1_IPv4_ADDRESS_FAMILY 
  192.168.1.128:
    peer_group: IPv4-UNDERLAY-PEERS
    description: SPINE2_IPv4_ADDRESS_FAMILY

my_bgp_neighbors: "{{ evpn_bgp_neighbors | combine(underlay_bgp_neighbors) }}"
```

Finally, back in my `group_vars` file, I referenced the combined dictionary:

```
router_bgp:
  neighbors: "{{ my_bgp_neighbors }}"
```

I did not need to make any modifications to my playbook. I only made changes to group_vars and host_vars files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: *"**Keep my first two IP addresses at the group level, but also define additional IP addresses at the host level**"*

A: Combine the dictionary within the *host_vars*. For example, given the inventory

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
[group1]
srv1
```

and the *group_vars*

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/group1.yml 
bgp_neighbors:
  1.1.1.1:
    peer_group: EVPN-OVERLAY-PEERS
    description: SPINE1_EVPN_ADDRESS_FAMILY
  1.1.1.2:
    peer_group: EVPN-OVERLAY-PEERS
    description: SPINE2_EVPN_ADDRESS_FAMILY
```

combine the dictionary *bgp_neighbors* with *bgp_neighbor_01* and create the variable *my_bgp_neighbors* within the *host_vars*

```yaml
shell> cat host_vars/srv1.yml
bgp_neighbor_01:
  peer_group: '{{ peer_group_name }}'
  description: '{{ description }}'
my_bgp_neighbors: '{{ bgp_neighbors|default({})|
                      combine({"bgp_neighbor_01": bgp_neighbor_01}) }}'
```

Then the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: srv1
  vars:
    peer_group_name: my-peer-group-name
    description: my-description
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: my_bgp_neighbors
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [srv1] => 
  my_bgp_neighbors:
    1.1.1.1:
      description: SPINE1_EVPN_ADDRESS_FAMILY
      peer_group: EVPN-OVERLAY-PEERS
    1.1.1.2:
      description: SPINE2_EVPN_ADDRESS_FAMILY
      peer_group: EVPN-OVERLAY-PEERS
    bgp_neighbor_01:
      description: my-description
      peer_group: my-peer-group-name
```

---

Unfortunately, it's not possible to combine dictionaries recursively within *host_vars*

```yaml
shell> cat host_vars/srv1.yml
bgp_neighbor_01:
  peer_group: '{{ peer_group_name }}'
  description: '{{ description }}'
bgp_neighbors: '{{ bgp_neighbors|default({})|
                   combine({"bgp_neighbor_01": bgp_neighbor_01}) }}'
```

would crash

> Error was a <class ''ansible.errors.AnsibleError''>, original message: recursive loop detected in template string: {{ bgp_neighbors|default({})| combine({"bgp_neighbor_01": bgp_neighbor_01}) }}'

Answer (score 1):

Why not change the group_vars to

```
  bgp_neighbour:
    - neighbour:
      ip: 1.1.1.1:
      peer_group: EVPN-OVERLAY-PEERS
      description: SPINE1_EVPN_ADDRESS_FAMILY
    - neighbour: 
      ip: 1.1.1.2:
      peer_group: EVPN-OVERLAY-PEERS
      description: SPINE2_EVPN_ADDRESS_FAMILY
    - neighbour:
      ip: '{{ bgp_neighbor_01 | default('empty')}}'             
      peer_group: '{{ peer_group_name }}'
      description: '{{ description }}'
```

and loop over that in a for loop and stop when ip is empty?
Also check https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable

Comment: I actually used this option, which you suggested, but using my own Jinja template, which allows me to re-structure my yaml definition in the way you suggested. The problem is that I am using an Ansible role (made by someone else), which expects a pre-defined yaml structure that is in my example, and I am not certain how to work around it.

Comment: Hi Sambo9, I would bite the bullet and refactor the role to what works ;). Good luck!